# "How do I delete my account"? has an incorrect & confusing screenshot

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-accounts, help-center

On the [How do I delete my account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleting-account) page within the Help Center, the 2nd screenshot should **not** have a delete link visible:

[image]

Since a user who *has* voted or posted's user page looks like this (*sans-*delete):

> [image]

Comment: Man, this would be a good situation for "EEK! My delete button is missing!"

Comment: But you missed the red circle around "edit"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screenshot has been updated and no longer shows a delete link.